# Highlight all matching words on double click in gedit

Tags: text-editor, gedit

IDEs like Eclipse, CodeBlocks and editors like Notepad++ highlights all instances of a double clicked word. I miss this feature in gedit. Of course, I can do Ctrl+k to highlight all instanced, but it is weird. Is there anyway this feature can be added to gedit by way of plugins? Are there any other editors which can do this in Linux,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this plugin does want you want:

```
git clone http://github.com/mmuell23/mmuell23.git
cp -r mmuell23/gedittools/* ~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins
```

Activate plug-in in gedit preferences and configure it as you wish.

Credits to https://github.com/mmuell23/mmuell23

Answer (score 6):

I just blogged about writing plugins for Gedit 3 (which are not compatible with Gedit 2). If you know Python and have Gedit 3 yet, this plugin would not be that difficult. You'd want to implement the Gedit.ViewActivatable interface and utilize the search function provided with the Gedit.Document API.

[Writing Plugins for Gedit 3 with Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20150216231821/http://www.micahcarrick.com/writing-plugins-for-gedit-3-in-python.html)